# Writing a Unit Test to ensure dynamic proxy creation by testing for IEntityWithChangeTracker (EF4)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, entity-framework, unit-testing, .net-4.0, nunit

I've been working through Julie Lerman's books on Entity Framework, and I've run into somewhat of a snag...

In "Programming Entity Framework DbContext" on page 66 Julie suggests writing a Unit Test to make sure that dynamic proxies are being created, since the requirements for getting Entity Framework to create change tracking proxies are fairly simple, but also very easy to miss.

With that being said, I followed the general structure of Julie's example to write the following test for my code:

```
[Test]
public void IsDynamicProxy()
{
    using (var scienceFairToGoContext = new ScienceFairToGoContext())
    {
        var scienceFair = scienceFairToGoContext.ScienceFairs.Create();
        Assert.IsTrue(scienceFair is IEntityWithChangeTracker);
    }
}
```

When I hover over the scienceFair object its pretty obvious its a change tracking proxy

```
System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.ScienceFair_D3C57A2F699E75F716E63553D950EF7EC75F0C603F69093FCD78122CC0D6452C
```

...but whenever I run the unit test it always fails because "scienceFair is IEntityWithChangeTracker" always evaluates to false.

It appears as though [someone else ran into this issue as well and posted it to the O'Reilly forums](http://forums.oreilly.com/topic/85119-how-to-test-if-ef-creates-dynamic-proxy/), but there doesn't seem to be a solution posted, nor do my Google searches return any type of answer.

I'm currently using Visual Studio 2010, EF4, NUnit, and running my tests through ReSharper.  It's also worth mentioning that if run the code in a simple console application and debug it I get the same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it looks like I figured out the issue.  While working through Julie's book, I thought it would be a good idea to have all of the entities inherit from a base class, ScienceFairToGoEntity.

It looks like I forgot to mark the 4 properties I had on the base class (InsertBy, InsertDate, UpdateBy, UpdateDate) as virtual, so the dynamic proxies were for Lazy Loading/ Relationship Fix-up and not for Change Tracking.

Answer (score 0):

It's weird to find this non-working piece of code in such a good book. You can however execute you test by:

```
using (var scienceFairToGoContext = new ScienceFairToGoContext())
{
    var scienceFair = scienceFairToGoContext.ScienceFairs.Create();
    Assert.IsTrue(scienceFair.GetType().IsSubclassOf(typeof(ScienceFair)));
}
```

although it is less generally applicable when there are entities in inheritance hierarchies. With derived entities you'd have to use

```
scienceFairToGoContext.BaseEntities.Create<TDerivedEntity>()
```

Comment: I like this solution, but there's one thing I'm concerned about.  I implemented the test like you suggested, however when I went and removed the virtual keyword from one of the scalar properties in the ScienceFair class, I noticed that a Dynamic Proxy was still being created, and the test was still marked as passing.  

I can only assume that this was a Dynamic Proxy for relationship fix-up as one of the rules for change tracking proxies is that all properties must be marked as virtual.  Is there any way to identify that this is change tracking proxy in the test?